# Admin, Teacher and Student, if a student is not logged out and you open a new tab trying to access admin you will bypass login

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a project as that has admin, teacher and student. They all have login forms and redirect to different based on who logged in, thus i have 3 folders student folder, admin folder and teacher folder and afer each one login the page will take them to the appropriate pages in their folders but without destroying the session it redirects user to the contents of admin pages. Personally i think it is because i put

```
session_start(); 
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){ 
    header("location:index.php?action=login"); 
}
```

to each page. please help what can i add to make sure that each individual user can access what they are required to access

Comment: so... you are checking if the username is (not)  set, but you dont check - what is the user name, and if that user name can access the page... your code is pretty clear.

Comment: format your code please

Comment: Set the rights level or username in the $_SESSION variable, and check it before serving any content.  If someone is still logged in and tries to access something they shouldn't it should throw up a denied message and/or redirect for reauthentication

Comment: @vladimir what can i do? I dont see anything wrong with that but when i open new tab and go to teacher login it bypass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least 2 issues here:

1. You assume that opening a new tab should not share the session with other tabs. I don't remember the details on PHP sessions. But, afaik, the state is stored on the server, and it uses some magic such as cookies to figure out what is the session that you are using. Problem is that two different tabs will hardly start a new session. In fact, the only possibility I see is if the session id is passed along with each request as a url or a header - then you can pick the correct session... which is pretty seldom used because use cases where such approach is needed are limited. (tbh, running 2 different sessions in 2 tabs is not a very real scenario). If you really want to run separate sessions on the same machine, you can try to run several incognito windows.
2. Second, more important issues, is the logic behind your application. Possibility of going to any page, once you have passed a login for any of the users means that the ritual of providing 3 logins into your system is totally useless, since there are no internal checks if the user is having rights to go to one or another page. Proper thing to do, is, once you logged in, to store the role (student, teacher, admin) as a session parameter. Then, on each page you should verify not only that the user name is set, but that stored role matches the role definition needed to view this particular page. If role does not match, then you should handle it appropriately. You may log user out, or display an access error message and provide a link tor redirect to allowed page.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir you said something that makes me rewrite the codes and use a single login that redirect user to pages based on their roles.